# remove whatever i want from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got a few keywords, symbols, letters etc I want to remove from my php string. I'm trying to add it but it doesn't work too well.

```
$string = preg_replace("/(?![=$'%-mp4mp3])\p{P}/u","", $check['title']);
```

pretty much I want to to remove word mp3, mp4, ./, apples from the string.

Please help guide me, thanks in advance!

Comment: What's with the flags (linux bash cron kill)?? Are you looking for a PHP solution or a Bash solution?

Comment: preferably php but sh is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex for that.

```
$string = "Your original string here";
$keywords = array('mp3', 'mp4');
echo str_replace($keywords, '', $string);
```

Comment: how would I remove stuff like: . /   ?

Comment: @thevoipman Just add it in the array: `array('mp3', 'mp4', './', 'apples')`

Comment: hmm, that is strange I have to test this again, i tried doing it and it doesn't work. this method is much easier to understand than regex. thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to do ' as well, and it doesn't like me so far

$badwords = array('(', ')', ''');

Comment: I guess doing it like this works:

$badwords = array('(', ')', "'");

Comment: @thevoipman You have to put it between double quotes or escape single quotes: array('(\', \')', ...) or array("(', ')" ...). It will match (', ')

Answer (score 3):

First: `[]` in regular expression introduces a character class. A hyphen is used to represent a character range between two symbols. So the reason your regular expression would make too many erasures (as I suppose) is because `[=$'%-mp4mp3]` means `=, $, ', everything from % to m (72 characters actually!), p, 3, 4`.

Second: your regular expression doesn't grab "bad" characters/keywords. Actually, you erase punctuation after bad characters/keywords, as negative lookahead is meta sequence (it is not included in match).

Change your regex to:

```
"/[=$'%-]|mp3|mp4/u"
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a major learning curve, and learning regex has caused me to loose a few brain cells lol. I could never understand regex what so ever! Thank you for your tip. I have managed to put other words between the mp3 and mp4. I tried removing the \ as well, so i just put \/ after the =. looks like this now: ("/[=\/$'%-.]|mp3|blah|blah|blah